# How to get content of the clicked paragraph?

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick

I have 10 paragraphs, each displaying a number from 1 to 10. I need a function that when clicking on the paragraph, reads the description of it an stores it in an array. So far I managed to do this:

```
function readValue(p) {
    var text = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML;

    console.log(text);
}
```

But when I'm clicking on the 5th paragraph, it still logs `1` to console.

How can it be changed to get the content of the paragraph that was actually clicked?

Comment: You should share your html as well, so that we can have a working snippet.

Comment: Sorry, that was a leftover fro ma previous try. It's actually text.

Comment: You should be avoiding getElement(s)By... Instead of this you should use querySelector(All). 
Then you can use addEventListener("click", function(){}) to watch for the click. Next get content with innerHTML, or another function like that

Answer (score 6):

You are reading and printing the value of only first paragraph. However, you need to read the text value of the clicked paragraph.

Event handler is passed an [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) object having a `target` property which holds a reference to the element which generated the event.

```js
let para = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

[...para].forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener('click', readValue));

function readValue(e) {
  let text = e.target.textContent;
  console.log(text);
}
```

```html
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0]` is saying you want the first paragraph found hence always the first one will be logged. I would solve this with event delegation by binding the `click` event to the parent and then checking if the `event.target` is a paragraph.
By delegating the event you'd also get the correct paragraph if you'd add more paragraphs programmatically later on.

```js
document.querySelector('#content').addEventListener('click', function(event){
  if(event.target.nodeName === 'P'){
    console.log(event.target.innerHTML)
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  <p>Paragraph 2</p>
  <p>Paragraph 3</p>
  <p>Paragraph 4</p>
  <p>Paragraph 5</p>
  <p>Paragraph 6</p>
  <p>Paragraph 7</p>
</div>
```